# Convergence of epigraphs formed by increasing sequence of $f_n$ to $f$

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

Suppose a sequence of $f_n$ is non-decreasing convergent to $f$( $f_n\geq f_{n-1}$). Is the epigraph formed by $f_n$ also convergence to that formed by $f$?
For instance $S_n = \{(x,y):f_n(x)\leq y\},S = \{(x,y):f(x)\leq y\}$.$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}S_n=S$?

We know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}S_n = \bigcap_{n\geq 1} S_n$. But I am not quite sure whether $\bigcap_{n\geq 1} S_n=S$ is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ satisfies $f \ge f_n$ for all $n$.
Thus
If $(x,y)$ satisfies $f(x) \le y$ then $f_n(x) \le f(x) \le y$. Thus $S \subseteq \bigcap_{n \ge 1} S_n$.

Conversely, if $(x,y)$ satisfies $f_n(x) \le y$ for all $n$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) \le y$, i.e. $f(x) \le y$. Thus $S \supseteq \bigcap_{n \ge 1} S_n$.

Comment: Hello, the definition of epigraph I used if from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigraph_(mathematics). I think it is correct.